# Failed to resolve Android.App.Fragment with Link SDK Only enabled

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, xamarin, linker-errors, android-fragmentactivity

I'm getting compile time error when linker option = "SDK Only" with "Failed to resolve Android.App.Fragment" message. It's all started when I added Google Maps support with FragmentActivity to my MonoDroid application.

With Linker option = "None" everything works just fine except of the fact that .apk became huge (~30mb instead of 7mb when link SDK Only enabled)

Error details:

```
The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve Android.App.Fragment
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkType(TypeReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeType(TypeDefinition type)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.InitializeAssembly(AssemblyDefinition assembly)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Initialize()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__20.MoveNext()
```

I found a lot of similar problems ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083289/failed-to-resolve-android-app-fragment-with-link-sdk-assemblies-only-enabled), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088227/linkassemblies-task-failed-with-resolutionexception-failed-to-resolve-android), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364813/monodroid-google-maps-v2-the-linkassemblies-task-failed-unexpectedly)) and the only proposed solution was to disable linker which is not the case for my app.

How can I diagnose and fix the issue?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing Mono.Android.Support.v4 classes everywhere?

Comment: Your error message (Failed to resolve Android.App.Fragment) indicates that somewhere you are using Android.Fragment instead of android.support.v4.app.Fragment. Have you tried searching for Fragment in your solution, and check the namespaces? If that not helps, I would try to find that class which is responsible for this error message (probably your Google Maps class) and comment out or temporarily delete them until the error gone. If you find out which class is causing this issue, copy your code here, and I'll try to find the problem for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same issue on and off for a while now.  Currently, I have had success in switching to the Alpha channel of Xamarin Updates and using the alpha builds of Xamarin.Android and Xamarin Studio.  Running those alphas, I have been able to make release builds with Linking enabled with no issues.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually GooglePlayServices Xamarin Component has been updated to 12.0.1 and not it could used without any errors even with "SDK Only" linker flag. You can use it right from component store without any bindings pre-compilation.